# hi i am using stockChart using highchart.js library. but i am unable to change x-axis label values, currently it is coming from formatter

Tags: highcharts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnFpl.png)
const options = {

```
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: xAxisTitle
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function (e: any) {
                return e.value;
            }
        },
        // tickLength:2,
        // type:'line',
        // tickAmount: 10,
        // min:0
        tickInterval: 30
    },
    series: [{
        marker: { enabled: false, fillColor: "#424c58", radius: 3 },
        data: seriesData,
        type: 'area',
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        }
    }],
    navigator: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
        height: '270',
        backgroundColor: null,
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            const _this: any = this;
            return `${_this.y}`;
        }
    }
};
```

I tried to create a custom method and pass it to formatter but like this

myCustomTemp = 0;

const formatLabels = () => {
myCustomTemp = myCustomTemp+1;

```
    if(seriesData && ((seriesData.length-1)==labels.length)){
        myCustomTemp= 0;
        return
    }
    if(seriesData && seriesData[myCustomTemp] && seriesData[myCustomTemp].x){
        return seriesData[myCustomTemp].x
    }
    return 10;
}
```

================================
xAxis: {
title: {
text: xAxisTitle
},
labels: {
formatter: function (e: any) {
const formatLabels1 = formatLabels();
return formatLabels1;
}
},

Comment: Hi @Manish Singh, Could you reproduce your problem in some online code editor? You can use this one: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u1tbgqv8/ as a base to start.